# Custom STL container wrapper report weird compiler error

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, wrapper

I have a C++ library (with over 50 source files) which uses a lot of STL routines with primary containers being `list` and `vector`. This has caused a huge code bloat and I would like to reduce the code bloat by creating another library which is essentially a wrapper 
over the `list` and `vector`.

I basically need a wrapper around `std::list` which works perfectly for the list container of any type.

Shown below is my list wrapper class.

```
template<typename T>
class wlist
{
private:
    std::list<T> m_list;

public:

    wlist();

    typedef std::list<void*>::iterator Iterator;
    typedef std::list<void*>::const_iterator CIterator;

    unsigned int size () { return m_list.size(); }
    bool empty () { return m_list.empty(); }
    void pop_back () { m_list.pop_back(); }
    void pop_front () { m_list.pop_front(); }
    void push_front (const T& item) { m_list.push_front(item); }
    void push_back (const T& item) { m_list.push_back(item); }
    bool delete_item (void* item);
    T& back () { return (m_list.empty()) ? NULL : m_list.back();}
    T& front () { return (m_list.empty()) ? NULL : m_list.front();}
    Iterator erase() { return m_list.erase(); }
    Iterator begin() { return (Iterator) m_list.begin(); }
    Iterator end() { return (Iterator) m_list.end(); }
};
```

File1.h:

```
class label{

public:
int getPosition(void);
setPosition(int x);

private:
wlist<text> _elementText; // used in place of list<text> _elementText;

}
```

File2.h:

```
class image {

private:

    void draw image() {
        //Used instead of list<label*>::iterator currentElement = _elementText.begin();
        wlist<label*>::iterator currentElement = _elementText.begin();
        currentElement->getPosition(); // Here is the problem.     
        currentElement ++;
    }
}
```

Invoking getPosition() bombs with the following error message:

```
error: request for member `getPosition' in `*(&currentElement)->std::_List_iterator<_Tp>::operator-> [with _Tp = void*]()', which is of non-class type `void*'
```

Type casting `getPosition()` to `label` type didn't work.  Additionally my iterators are of type `void*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the line

```
currentElement->getPosition();
```

won't work because `currentElement` is an iterator over `void*`s, not `label`s.  Since iterators over some type `T` act like `T*`s, this means that your `currentElement` iterator acts like a `label**`, and so writing the above code is similar to writing

```
(*currentElement).getPosition();
```

Here, the problem should be a bit easier to see - `*currentElement` is a `label*`, not a `label`, and so you can't use the dot operator on it.

To fix this, trying changing this code to

```
((label *)(*currentElement))->getPosition();
```

This dereferences the iterator and typecasts the `void*` to get a `label*`, then uses the arrow operator to call the `getPosition()` function on the `label` being pointed at.

Comment: How should I declare erase(), begin() and end() in wlist. My current declaration throws errors like: error: cannot convert `((std::list<label*, std::allocator<label*> >*)this)->std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::end [with _Tp = label*, _Alloc = std::allocator<label*>]()' from type `std::_List_iterator<label*>' to type `std::_List_iterator<void*>*'. I was also not able to declare the iterator to be of type T thats why I declared it as of type void*

Comment: I think that almost all of your problems are going to stem from the fact that your iterators are iterating over `void*`s, which really isn't the right way to do this.  I think that you really do want your iterators to have type `T`, and chances are that the problem is that if you tried to define them as `typedef std::list<T>::iterator iterator` you'd get a compiler error.  The correct way to do this is to write it as `typedef typename std::list<T>::iterator iterator`, since `std::list<T>::iterator` is a dependent type.  Try doing that and see if it simplifies things.

Answer (score 0):

Your iterator types seem to be declared in terms of `std::list<void*>::iterator`.  This doesn't sound right to me...

Comment: typedef std::list<T>::iterator Iterator; which threw a compilation error

Comment: error: type `std::list<T, std::allocator<_CharT> >' is not derived from type `wstl::wlist<T>' and derivation is not an option

Comment: @codebin: That should be `typedef typename std::list<T>::iterator Iterator;` (and for greater genericity, your Iterator might begin with lower-case i too). - As to your `void*` typedef, my compiler says that `list<T>::iterator` cannot be cast to `list<void*>::iterator`